# Nest.js bundle size too large by default

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, nestjs, nest

Upon running `nest build` command, I was expecting that the build would pick up only the imported modules from the `node_module` folder.

However, the command did not pick up only the relevent files and minifiy them. Instead, it picked up the `node_modules` directly from the root folder.

As a result, the final build size of the application is extremely large.

How can I reduce the bundle size?